# Changing Label text on ListBox event is not working while outside of UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the code below for a ListBox:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">Item1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item3</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:ListBox>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblTB" runat="server"/>
```

And this is the code behind the index changed event:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lblTB.Text = "You choose: " + ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

I don't want to put control label into UpdatePanel. How can I make this code run? Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine just add `ScriptManager`.Try this:

```
       <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"
onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
       <asp:ListItem Value="0">Item1</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item2</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item3</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:ListBox>
       </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
       <asp:Label ID="lblTB" runat="server"/>
```

Code behind should be.

```
   try
    { 
        HttpCookie getcook = Request.Cookies["saveme"];
        string check = getcook["saveme"].ToString();
        if (getcook["saveme"].Length > 0 &&      getcook["saveme"].ToString()!="none")
          {
             lblTB.Text = getcook["saveme"].ToString();
          }
        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("saveme");
            cookie["saveme"] = "none";
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        }

    }

    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTB.Text = "You choose: " + ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
        HttpCookie setcook =Request.Cookies["saveme"];
        setcook["saveme"] = lblTB.Text;
        setcook.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d); ;
        Response.Cookies.Add(setcook);
        Response.Redirect("updatepanelhere.aspx", false);
    }
```

Comment: Any error? where is the part not working? at your code behind?

Comment: Not error, but run nothing. I have post code behind above.

Comment: yes place it all.. It is working to me.. how about you in there?

Comment: If its work then mark this as answered.. thanks change this as your page name  Response.Redirect("updatepanelhere.aspx", false);